# is anyone able to identify what is worng with this code, i keep on getting a parsing error

Tags: java, csv

I am working on a project for coverting a discord bots output into a csv file for better tracking i keep geting a data parsing error and was wondering if anyone could spot the issue

```
Main.java:110: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error
```

First, the program prompts the user to enter the name of the CSV file, which is then stored in a variable called fileName. Next, it creates a new CSV file using this name and a BufferedWriter.

```
// prompt the user to name the CSV file
System.out.print("Enter the name of the CSV file: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = scanner.nextLine();

// create the CSV file
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
```

The program then writes the header row to the CSV file:

```
// write the header row to the CSV file
writer.write("Employee Name,Shift ID,Hours,Minutes,Seconds,Shift start date");
writer.newLine();
```

It initializes variables totalHours, totalMinutes, and totalSeconds to keep track of the totals for each employee. It also initializes a flag called done to indicate when the program should stop.

```
// initialize variables to keep track of totals
int totalHours = 0;
int totalMinutes = 0;
int totalSeconds = 0;

// initialize a flag to indicate whether the program is done
boolean done = false;
```

The program then enters a loop that continues until the done flag is set to true. Inside the loop, it prompts the user to enter the name of the employee and the shift data. The program then extracts the shift ID and duration from the shift data by using the substring method. It stores the shift ID in a variable called shiftId and the duration in a variable called durationString.

```
  // extract the shift ID and duration from the shift data
  String shiftId = shiftData.substring(0, shiftData.indexOf(" "));
  String durationString = shiftData.substring(shiftData.indexOf("Duration: ") + 10, shiftData.indexOf(" Started: "));
```

Next, it parses the duration into hours, minutes, and seconds. It first checks whether the duration string contains the word "hour". If it does, the duration is more than an hour. In this case, it extracts the number of hours by using the substring method and stores it in a variable called hours. It then extracts the minutes and seconds by using the substring method and storing them in variables called minutes and seconds, respectively.

If the duration string does not contain the word "hour", it means the duration is less than an hour. In this case, the program extracts the minutes and seconds in the same way as before and stores them in the minutes and seconds variables.

```
  // parse the duration into hours, minutes, and seconds
  int hours = 0;
  int minutes = 0;
  int seconds = 0;
  if (durationString.contains("hour")) {
    // the duration is more than an hour
    hours = Integer.parseInt(durationString.substring(0, durationString.indexOf(" hour")));
    String minutesAndSeconds = durationString.substring(durationString.indexOf(" hour") + 6);
    if (minutesAndSeconds.contains("minute")) {
                // the duration has both hours and minutes
      minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesAndSeconds.substring(0, minutesAndSeconds.indexOf(" minute")));
      seconds = Integer.parseInt(minutesAndSeconds.substring(minutesAndSeconds.indexOf(" minute") + 8, minutesAndSeconds.indexOf(" second")));
    } else {
      // the duration has only hours
      seconds = Integer.parseInt(minutesAndSeconds.substring(0, minutesAndSeconds.indexOf(" second")));
    }
  } else {
    // the duration is less than an hour
    minutes = Integer.parseInt(durationString.substring(0, durationString.indexOf(" minute")));
    seconds = Integer.parseInt(durationString.substring(durationString.indexOf(" minute") + 8, durationString.indexOf(" second")));
  }
```

Next, the program parses the start date from the shift data and stores it in a variable called startDate. It uses the substring method to extract the start date string and a SimpleDateFormat object to parse the start date string into a Date object.

```
  // parse the start date from the shift data
  String startDateString = shiftData.substring(shiftData.indexOf("Started: ") + 9, shiftData.indexOf(" Ended: "));
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
  Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(startDateString);
```

Finally, the program writes the employee name, shift ID, hours, minutes, seconds, and start date to the CSV file, separated by commas. It also updates the totalHours, totalMinutes, and totalSeconds variables by adding the hours, minutes, and seconds for the current shift.

```
  // write the data to the CSV file
  writer.write(employeeName + "," + shiftId + "," + hours + "," + minutes + "," + seconds + "," + startDate.toString());
  writer.newLine();

  // update the totals
  totalHours += hours;
  totalMinutes += minutes;
  totalSeconds += seconds;
```

After writing the shift data to the CSV file, the program prompts the user to enter a number indicating what to do next. If the user enters 1, the program continues to enter more shifts for the same employee. If the user enters 2, the program writes the totals for the previous employee to the CSV file, resets the totals, and prompts the user to enter shifts for a new employee. If the user enters 3, the program writes the totals for the previous employee to the CSV file, closes the file, and sets the done flag to true to exit the loop. If the user enters any other number, the program prompts the user again.

```
  // ask the user what to do next
  System.out.print("Enter 1 to enter more shifts for this employee, 2 to enter shifts for a new employee, or 3 to save and close the file: ");
  int action = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.nextLine(); // consume the newline character
  if (action == 1) {
    // continue entering shifts for the same employee
  } else if (action == 2) {
    // write the totals for the previous employee to the CSV file
    writer.write(employeeName + " Total," + totalHours + "," + totalMinutes + "," + totalSeconds);
    writer.newLine();

    // reset the totals
    totalHours = 0;
    totalMinutes = 0;
    totalSeconds = 0;
  } else if (action == 3) {
    // write the totals for the previous employee to the CSV file
    writer.write(employeeName + " Total," + totalHours + "," + totalMinutes + "," + totalSeconds);
    writer.newLine();

    // close the file and set the done flag to true
    writer.close();
    done = true;
  } else {
    // invalid input, ask the user again
    System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again.");
  }
```

Finally, the program closes the Scanner object and exits.

```
}

// close the scanner
scanner.close();
```

}
}

i have tried using a diffrent way of inputing as a csv and get the same result.

Comment: You probably have a mismatched number of opening and closing braces, i.e. `{` and `}`

Comment: ^, that error seems like you are missing one possibly. Try to auto-indent the code using an IDE and see where it gets messed up and searching around there.

Comment: The error warning shows that the error comes in line number  `Main.java:110` .  Please check in your IDE and tell what line is line number 110. That will be a hint for us to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the bracket here

```
     }//remove this bracket
     
     // close the scanner
     scanner.close();
     }}
```